# After Installing Win 8 Pro and IIS 8 - missing StaticFileModule

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-8, iis-8

I've made new installation Win 8 Pro + IIS 8, but any static content (png and etc.) on my web site not working, because StaticFileModule in Modules IIS8 and static.dll are missing.

What command enable StaticFileModule (static.dll) in IIS8 ?

Answer (score 5):

Try installing the "Static content" feature using the "Turn Windows features on or off" menu:

[image: Win8 screenshot]

If for some reason the module is missing in ISS after installation, you can try to add it manually (use the "Configure Native Modules" option and copy the information from the screenshot):

[image: IIS modules]

Comment: Yes, that item is ON, but StaticFileModule is absent. I've reinstalled IIS, but result is the same

Comment: To be honest, this is quite strange. I just started my virtual Windows 8 installation (Windows 8 Pro on VMware) and did a fresh install of IIS (just select the "World Wide Web Services" node in "Windows Features"), and it was all good. Check the edited answer if that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

try installing IIS again. Turn features off and restart first.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to reinstall windows

Comment: installing Windows again helped me.