# Add more than 1 folder (network path) to static files with Django on IIS

Tags: django, iis

I have a django website deployed on an IIS Server.  in it, I have 2 different network paths I need to access via static

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    "//server1/Shared1/folder/", "//Server2/folder2/",
]
```

Now, currently my IIS has a static virtual directory that is set to "server1"
this allows me to work with all the files I have in that shared network drive and opertate properly.

[image]

The issue comes when I try to work with any files in the "server2" I don't know how to add it. I understand that exists something called "static root" but for that I need to do a "collect static" in this case, I can't do a collect static since both servers have over 60gb of data that I need to access.

Is there a way I'm not seeing for adding this second server to be able to be used via IIS?

[image]

Comment: Is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312590/how-to-fetch-static-css-files-with-django-on-iis) helpful to your problem ?

Comment: Hello Hury, no, it doesn't help, I have the setup explained here. I am able to serve static content, my issue is trying to serve static content from 2 different places without runnig hte collectstatic (since the folder is big)  I'm able to serve with a virtual directory static to 1 path but I don't know how to serve my 2nd path

Comment: Do you mean add two paths as "Physical path" for static virtual directory ?

Comment: yes, right now, as the screenshot, my virtual directory points to 1 path (network drive) however I have content I also need to serve from a 2nd network drive, and I don't have where to point this one since the "static" alias is already used. does this makes sense?

Comment: from the screenshot, my static alias in IIS points to  "//server1/Shared1/folder/" but I need to also access to the static files in "//Server2/folder2/" where and how do I set this in iis?

Comment: In my opinion, we can't specify two physical paths for virtual path. But as a workaround, maybe you can have a try with create a new shared folder which contains the two folder (`//server1/Shared1/folder/` and `//Server2/folder2/`). Then use the new created shared folder as physical path.

Comment: to create them with shortcuts would work? because they're in different network drives, I can't just move them to the same location and then point to that one. I'll try creating a folder in my webserver, that has shortcuts to the network drives of the 2 locations, and then point to that folder, is this what you mean?

Comment: I'm not sure if this workaround can work, just suggest you have a try.

Comment: yes, I understand, but I understood correctly your suggestion?  thank you!

Comment: Yes, I think your description is what I mean.

Comment: uhm, sadly doesn't work, when I get a full path including the shortcut, it breaks the link since the shortcut changes the absolute path to the network one :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that has the same type of issue. I was able to do this by adding a second virtual directory as subfolder for the first one

-The first one pointing to shared drive X
-The second one as subfolder pointing to shared drive Y with an alias

and then I added a call for this second folder where needed such as "static/2ndserver"

with this was able to get the files from both separate network locations without having to do a "collectstatic" and bring them to a third place.

[image]

and in the template I call it by this:

```
<td><a href=' {% static  "/subfolder/" %}{{ datarow.path }}'>Open Document</a></td>
```