# Deploy static file of Django on IIS

Tags: django, iis, deployment, static

I read some similar issue on Stack Overflow but still stuck with this problem. The web Django can deploy on IIS well except CSS style for admin and all CSS.

What I tried:

1. Use whitenoise -> I got error when I wrote whitenoise tag in middleware. then I stopped use this way
2. Use add virtual directory
   more information -> I created virtual enviroment
   venv_>my django>app folder
   honestly, I really don't know where virtual directory (named static) should be, then I tried at

   1. default web site
   2. venv_
   3. my project folder (my static folder after use collectstatic Django)
      I tried to use path physical to (my static folder after use collectstatic Django)
      it still not working

More information:

I used findstatic but got another path not (collectstatic path in my project app)
it is in my venv_ package?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312590/how-to-fetch-static-css-files-with-django-on-iis i tried this one too

Comment: What about host static files on IIS directly and refer them as links on Django application? For example `http://xxxx/abc/xyz.css`.