# django web server running with iis doesn't run static css js image files

Tags: django, iis, django-staticfiles

I have a django web server project running on ISP and static file is not working

How do I make changes to Internet Information Services (IIS) and web cofig file for static files to work?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>

    <appSettings>
    <!-- Required settings -->
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()" />
    <!-- Your django path -->
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pax_web_server_app" /> 
    <!-- Your djangoname.settings -->
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="pax_web_server_app.settings" />
    </appSettings>

    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>

            <add name="paxsite" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Python311\python.exe|C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" />

        </handlers>
        <staticContent>

            <mimeMap fileExtension=".tab" mimeType="static/css" />

        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I did the [instructions on the microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap) but it still didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create virtual directory in iis with the name of **static** and point the path to that virtual directory with your actual static folder

Here is the link you can refer for the more details:

[How to fetch static CSS files with django on IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312590/how-to-fetch-static-css-files-with-django-on-iis)